# How do I link MVT tiles to the source attribute of a vector layer?

Tags: angular, postgresql, datatable, openlayers, postgis

In a PostgreSQL table, I have a columns of type geometries. I convert them to `MVT` via PostGIS `ST_AsMVT` and `st_asmvtgeom`. I'd like to know how to link the `MVT` tiles to the `source` attribute of a vector layer in OpenLayers.

**My code:**

```
return new VectorLayer ({
    source: source,
    style: new Style ({
        fill: new Fill ({
            color: fillColor
        }),
        
        stroke: new Stroke({
            color: strokeColor,
            lineDash: [2],
            width: 2,
        }),
        
        text: new Text ({
            font: 'Normal 12px Arial',
            text: '' + text,
            fill: new Fill ({
                color: '#000000'
            }),
            
            stroke: new Stroke ({
                color: '#000000',
                width: 1
            }),
            // offsetX: -45,
            // offsetY: 0,
            // rotation: 0
        })
    })
});
}
```

Comment: You need to know the tile extent to display an MVT tile in a Vector layer, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop-custom-mvt.html  In most cases it would be better to use a VectorTile layer and VectorTile source.

Comment: @Mike thanks for info provided.i do not want to drag and drop i want the source of the vector layer read the data from the database.is it possible, would you please provided simple example

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layer-forked-xdqxg?file=/main.js

Comment: @Mike but please i would like the source to be the mvt tiles/geometries of the columns iin the database i have, is it possible?please have alook at the first image here:https://tilezen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: If you want more than one tile from a tile grid you should use VectorTile layer and VectorTiile source https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/osm-vector-tiles.html